Flask Gunicorn Open AI chatgpt proxy api timeout
I have a flask project, with gunicorn gevent setup to have async workers.
I have a Open AI chat-gpt proxy route which times out on large datasets api calls, more often than if I use same data directly to open ai instance in azure cloud.
I am looking for options on optimization. I keep getting 499 errors (client-side terminated request).
I tried gevent which helped but I am still getting 499 errors.
This is the requirements file i have :-
azure-identity Flask==2.3.2 openai==0.27.7 azure-search-documents==11.4.0b6 azure-storage-blob==12.17.0 python-dotenv==1.0.0 azure-cosmos==4.5.0 applicationinsights opencensus-ext-azure requests bleach gevent
I am thinking to replace requests with an async request, but also open to other solutions.
